# Drawing layout for Java swing

Tags: java, swing

The above layout, I draw it using HTML. It show who is available to pick the phone.
(It's polling data and show employee's status, and it works well)

and now I'm studying Java, so I'd like to make this program using Java too.

but No idea how to draw this layout. I read AWT and swing part in Java book already, but no idea..

I guess, firstly make container for wrapping. and 4 panels for department column.

and **how to make the person's status box that contain name and lunch-out time.**

Please help me to get picture of Java layout and swing.

<s>If it is not asking too much, could you please write the source code?</s>
**Sorry for asking Code!**

Thank you!

Comment: Writing the source code is asking too much actually. We could point you in the right direction though. Do you want users to interact with the interface, ie, click on a name to do some action, or is it just for display purposes.

Comment: I've got to second those who ask you **not** to ask others to write your code. That's just not appropriate here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code would be rather long. A good GUI editor, like that of the NetBeans IDE would be a help.
The structure is as follows:

- JFrame, set the Layout (of the content pane) to BorderLayout
- - JScrollPane
- - - JPanel with BoxLayout oriented to the X-Axis
- - - - JPanel 1 with BoxLayout oriented to the Y-Axis
- - - - - JLabel column title
- - - - - JPanel/JLabel with as text maybe < html > < body > < b > name < / b > time
- - - - - ...
- - - - JPanel 2 with BoxLayout oriented to the Y-Axis
- - - - JPanel 3 with BoxLayout oriented to the Y-Axis
- - - - JPanel 4 with BoxLayout oriented to the Y-Axis

An abstract data model to your own design will help managing it.

You can easily add a rounded border, and such.

Comment: +1 for many points, but especially for pointing out that an IDE such as NetBeans can both speed development time, and use standard layout managers (nested).

Comment: Thank you! !! JPanel/JLabel with as text maybe < html > < body > < b > name < / b > time !! <-= this is exactly what I need!

Comment: Could you tell me WHY need to use JPanel/JLabel ? (I mean why not only JLabel). I tried to use only JLabel then I got a problem with center alignment, I couldn't make it center alignment. is it because this? or there is the other reason? thank you :)

Comment: It was either stop with a JLabel, or construct a JPanel with on it maybe two JLabels or such. A JLabel has a provision for an icon, so one maybe has to check the insets: `label.setInsets(new Insets(1, 1, 1, 1));`. For the rest, if you've added a rounded border, you can control the correct width.

Comment: May I ask one more question?, do you know how to set label width to maximum (parent (box layout)panel width). I tried, 1)label.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100,200)); (x) 2)label.setSize(new Dimension(testPanel.getSize().width-10,50)); (x) 3) label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(testPanel.getSize().width-10,50)); (x)... Thank you very much!

Comment: Layouting works more from the inner to the outer. After constructing everything one calls JFrame's pack(). Setting a fixed minimum and preferred size on the label is the normal way.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, asking us to write the code for you is most-often too much to ask.

What have you tried?
Have you gotten to displaying a [`JFrame`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html)?  (your main window, unless you're doing an [`Applet`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info))
Have you learned about [`JLabels`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html)?  (this is what you'll use to create the status fields)
Have you learned about [`LayoutManagers`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)? (hint, you'll probably want a gridlayout to start).

After you've learned these three things (and a lot more, frankly) pretty well, it's time to ask:
How is your data stored?  Is it in a database?  A file on a server?  A service on a server?  Local data/file?

These are the questions you'll have to answer.  We can't answer them for you, unfortunately.

Comment: Nice links. Well, 3 of them anyway.  For applets, I prefer http://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info ;)

Comment: Awesome!  I didn't even know tag descriptions were that in depth and resourceful.  Thanks!

Comment: Well, the tag descriptions that *I* wrote are generally that good.  :-)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, and sorry for asking code. But, actually for me, data store, database and servers is easier then draw layout. And I didn't mention about this, but I tried until grid layout and I was just wondered how I could draw the person's status box (like, it should be 2D box, panel or label?)